# Map two related enums?

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums which are related:

Enum1:

```
public enum HttpStatusCode {

    ACCEPTED(202),
    OK(200),
    CREATED(201),
    BAD_REQUEST(400),
    NOT_FOUND(404),
    METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED(405),
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT (408),
    FORBIDDEN(403),
    CONFLICT(409),
    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(500),
    NOT_IMPLEMENTED(501);

    private int httpStatusCode;

    private HttpStatusCode(int name) {
        this.httpStatusCode = name;
    }

    public int getHttpStatusCode() {
        return httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Enum2:

```
public enum ProtocolStatusCode {

    ACCEPTED(1000),
    OK(2000),
    CREATED(2001),
    BAD_REQUEST(4000)

private int protocolStatusCode;

    private ProtocolStatusCode(int protocolStatusCode) {
        this.protocolStatusCode = protocolStatusCode;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return protocolStatusCode;
    }
}
```

These two enums values are related in a mapping, for example

Protocol status code 2000 (OK) has mapping with 200 (OK).

So in my code I will get the ProtocolStatusCode (2000) and corresponding to that I will need HttpStatusCode (200).

I was thinking of maintaing the ProtocolStatusCode enum as

```
ACCEPTED(1000, 202),
    OK(2000, 200)
```

So like this when I get 2000, I will reverse lookup the enum to get OK and then call a getter to get the second value (200) related to 2000.

Any better approach ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can in 2nd enum add a field, which is the type of the first enum. Then you don't have to search through the first enum array to find the right object. Something like:

```
enum A{
    A_FOO(1),
    A_BAR(2);
    private  int code;

    private A(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}

enum B{
    B_FOO(1000,A_FOO),
    B_BAR(2000,A_BAR);

    private int code;
    private A status;

    private B(int code, A status) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public A getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

thus, if the codes in the B enum is unique, you can implement a method like `getBbyCode()` then you have `B.A` too.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you want to go one-way or both ways.

One simple mechanism would be to hold the equivalent in the enum and specify it in the constructor.

```
public enum HttpStatusCode {

    ACCEPTED(202, ProtocolStatusCode.ACCEPTED),
    OK(200, ProtocolStatusCode.OK),
    CREATED(201,ProtocolStatusCode.CREATED);

    private int httpStatusCode;
    private final ProtocolStatusCode protocolEquivalent;

    private HttpStatusCode(int name, ProtocolStatusCode protocolEquivalent) {
        this.httpStatusCode = name;
        this.protocolEquivalent = protocolEquivalent;
    }

    public int getHttpStatusCode() {
        return httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Alternatively - you could build two maps:

```
static final Map<HttpStatusCode, ProtocolStatusCode> protocolStatus = new EnumMap(HttpStatusCode.class);
static final Map<ProtocolStatusCode, HttpStatusCode> httpStatus = new EnumMap(ProtocolStatusCode.class);

private static void equivalent(HttpStatusCode http, ProtocolStatusCode protocol) {
    protocolStatus.put(http, protocol);
    httpStatus.put(protocol, http);
}

static {
    equivalent(HttpStatusCode.ACCEPTED, ProtocolStatusCode.ACCEPTED);
    equivalent(HttpStatusCode.OK, ProtocolStatusCode.OK);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for the program is in your requirement.

> Protocol status code 2000 (OK) has mapping with 200 (OK).

It means that you need a has-a relationship in Object Oriented Programming.

```
public enum ProtocolStatusCode {


    OK(2000, HttpStatusCode.OK);//so goes others


    private int protocolStatusCode;
    private HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode;

    private ProtocolStatusCode(int protocolStatusCode, 
                               HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode) {
        this.protocolStatusCode = protocolStatusCode;
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpStatusCode getHttpStatusCode(){//new
        return this.httpStatusCode;
    }

    public int getHttpStatusCodeVal(){//new method for lookup
        return this.getHttpStatusCode().getHttpStatusCode();
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return protocolStatusCode;
    }


}
```

Code might have typos as I typed it raw on web. :)